# How python multi-process forking works with respect to resources sharing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
class Job:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
class A:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
    def run(self,job):
        self.x+=1
        print(id(self.x),self.x,job.name)

    def mul_process_test(self):
        j1=Job('hello')
        j2=Job('world')
        p1=mp.Process(target=self.run,args=(j1,))
        p2=mp.Process(target=self.run,args=(j2,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
if __name__ =='__main__':
    a=A(1)
    a.mul_process_test()
    print(id(a.x),a.x)
```

The result of the above code is:

```py
10919360 2 hello
10919360 2 world
10919328 1
```

It seems the `self.x` in the two processes have the same id ,10919360 (which does not make sense to me), but have different id from the main process(which makes sense to me).
I am using python3.5 in Linux, as the document states, the default start method take fork-like fashion to start a new process. I was wondering why the id of `self.x` in the two processes are the same. Is there anything being shared across the three processes (main process and the two processes started with `mp.Process`)?

Comment: When I run your example, I only see the *print* from the main process - Windows.

Comment: @wwii, I am on Linux ubuntu14

Comment: @wwii: Windows doesn't (and can't) use `fork` to implement `Process`, so the behavior there is expected to be quite different. It might also behave differently for flushing buffers (worker processes typically exit with `os._exit` which doesn't explicitly do so), so you might need to add `flush=True` as an argument to the `print`s in the workers.

Comment: Change the run method to `def run(self,job):  self.x = self.x + 'foo'...` and instantiate with `a=A('abercrombie')` ... then you'll see a difference.

Comment: I think that you might be interested in getting familiar with how [fork works on Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)), if you are not yet. The behavior you observe is the consequence of how processes work in Linux. Above that the answer by ShadowRanger seems adequate and very detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id`s in CPython (the Python reference interpreter) are just memory addresses. And CPython (as an implementation detail) uses a small `int` cache such that all numbers from -5 to 256 are singletons. So your child processes copy the same virtual address table from the parent, and inherit the same small `int` cache. When they compute `self.x += 1`, they look up the same cached value of `2`.

Now, technically, thanks to CPython reference counting, the physical RAM underlying each process's of `2` won't be the same (the reference count updates force the copy on write page to be copied in the children as soon as the values are referenced, increasing the reference count). But copy-on-write semantics preserve the virtual memory address, they just remap the underlying physical pages, and CPython's `id` is reporting the (unchanged) virtual memory address. So for any value from -5 to 256, it would be expected for the `id`s to be identical in `fork`-ed child processes. You'd only expect a discrepancy for values outside that range, and even then, you might end up with similar IDs for a while if the runtime behavior was the same (because the allocator state is also copied on `fork`; until something divergent or non-deterministic changes the allocation pattern, allocated memory addresses would continue to follow the same pattern).

Comment: Noob question: So virtual address spaces seem to be namespaced (am I right?); is there any global namespace? And if there is won't it make duplicates?

Comment: @heemayl: Namespaced? Not sure I know what you mean by that. Each process has its own virtual address table, but the virtual addresses are resolved by the OS, and the OS can map a given physical page to one or more processes. You can kind of pretend that the OS has a namespace for each process ID that determines which virtual memory table to use for looking up physical pages in the user-mode address space I guess? The "global namespace" in this analogy is the kernel-mode section of the virtual address table, but that's not something you generally work with (directly anyway) in Python.

Comment: But yes, the kernel mode section of the address space is shared by every process; if, for whatever reason, you and another process get a usable pointer to kernel mode memory with the same address, it points to the same memory in both processes; for user mode memory, even if the pointers *appear* to point to the same memory address, that implies nothing about whether they are actually sharing memory (they might be, in the case of memory mapping the same file or copy-on-write memory, but more likely independent memory mappings will end up at different addresses in each process).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.